# How to change the mouse cursor to arrow in Iterm2 in VIM

Tags: vim, iterm2

After using MacVim for a long time, I've switched to using VIM in Iterm2 directly. Although, I don't use the mouse often, when I do I miss MacVim's mouse cursor switching to `Arrow` when in normal mode, and to `IBar` when in insert mode and to `Drag` when moving the mouse over a split (to drag it).

Is it possible to configure the mouse cursor to react to the content that VIM presents and if so, how?

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: @romainl thanks for replying. If possible, can you elaborate on that, please? What is preventing this from being possible?

Comment: Being a Cocoa application, MacVim is able to interact with the desktop environment. Vim is incapable of interacting with the desktop environment because it is simply not aware of it and vice-versa.